# jQuery: :-selector vs class-selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

jQuery-ui dialogs can be selected using either `$(":ui-dialog")` or `$(".ui-dialog")`, but the elements of the repective sets being returned are not equivalent. For instance

```
$(":ui-dialog").each(function() {
    if ($(this).dialog("option", "modal")) {
        console.log("dialog is modal");
    } else {
        console.log("dialog is non-modal");
    }
});
```

works as expected, while

```
$(".ui-dialog").each(function() {
    if ($(this).dialog("option", "modal")) {
        console.log("dialog is modal");
    } else {
        console.log("dialog is non-modal");
    }
});
```

fails with an error message on the first call to the dialog method. What is the difference between the selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the [widget pseudo selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085.aspx#sec15)

The difference is `.ui-dialog` returns elements with class `ui-dialog` but the dialog widget is not initialized on these elements, these are created by the dialog widget when it was initialized on another element.

where as `:ui-dialog` returns the elements on which the dialog widget was actually initialized on.

Ex:

```
<div class="dialog">1</div>
<div class="dialog">2</div>
<div class="dialog">3</div>
$('.dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});
```

in the above case

`.dialog` and `:ui-dialog` returns the above 3 div elements where as `:ui-dialog` returns some elements which was created by the dialog widget

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TcBXE/)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.erichynds.com/blog/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets

**Method 3: widget pseudo-selector**

> In the #jquery IRC channel, Adam Sontag of the yayQuery fame noted an
>   undocumented feature of the widget factory: automatic pseudo selector
>   generation for all widgets. With this, it is super simple to query the
>   DOM for all widgets of a certain type:

```
// gimme all dialogs
$(":ui-dialog");
```

> The selector above returns an object of DOM elements each instance was
>   created on. No need to maintain your own cache or store the DOM
>   element inside each widget. Closing all other open dialog instances
>   using this pseudo selector is trivial:

```
// ui.dialog.js

open: function(){

    // close all open dialogs, excluding this instance
    $(":ui-dialog").not(this.element).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.dialog("isOpen")){
            $this.dialog("close");
        }
    });

    // rest of open code here
}
```

---

I have tested both selectors in the console on this page: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/default.html

```
$('.ui-dialog')
[
<div class=​"ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex=​"-1" role=​"dialog" aria-describedby=​"dialog" aria-labelledby=​"ui-id-1" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ height:​ auto;​ width:​ 300px;​ top:​ 341.5px;​ left:​ 711px;​ display:​ block;​">​
    <div class=​"ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">​…​</div>​
    <div id=​"dialog" class=​"ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style=​"width:​ auto;​ min-height:​ 107px;​ max-height:​ none;​ height:​ auto;​">​…​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
    <div class=​"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style=​"z-index:​ 90;​">​</div>​
</div>​
]
```

-

```
$(':ui-dialog')
[
<div id=​"dialog" class=​"ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style=​"width:​ auto;​ min-height:​ 107px;​ max-height:​ none;​ height:​ auto;​">​
    <p>​…​</p>​
</div>​
]
```

So .ui-dialog selects the entire dialog element and :ui-widget selects only the dialog widget of which lets you call the dialog methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(':ui-dialog')` selector is a custom jQuery UI selector:

```
// create selector for plugin
$.expr[ ":" ][ fullName ] = function( elem ) {
    return !!$.data( elem, name );
};
```

which goes through the selected elements and returns the element with additional plugin defined data (dialog in this case) object.

So the first each will return a jQuery UI dialog object, the second a simple jQuery object with no reference with the jQuery UI dialog, so will raise errors by accessing directly its properties/methods.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jUUhB/

PS: thank you for the question I didn't know about this before today :-)